# Jasmine spec runner and directive templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

In my angular app I have two different ways to run unit tests.  The first is to just run karma.  The 2nd way is to use the jasmine spec runner (I find it easier to debug using this).  I have directives whose templates are a little complicated so I put them in html files and use templateUrl.  My test run fine with karma as I am using karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor to process my templates.  My problem is that since the jasmine spec runner does not use karma config file I am unable to use the templates running tests this way.  I have found plenty of similar questions here but every solution is for the first way using karma and karma.config.  Can anybody tell me if they have figured out how to test directives with templateUrls using the spec runner (i.e. no karma.config).  Please keep in mind that the templates are too complicated to manually put them in templateCache (i.e. I don't want to have to do that if there is another way).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was create a grunt task called specrunner.  Then that task runs wiredep, ng-templates so that way all of the html is actually in a template.js.  hope this helps somebody else.